# Is it "same as me" or "same like me"?

Tags: as-like

1. Your team is working on the same research areas as me.
2. Your team is working on the same research areas like me.

I am not sure which of the above sentences is correct. My grammar check program tells me that 1 is wrong, but it sounds ok to me (even better than 2). Can you help me understand?

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be _...the same... as I am_ [working on]. (2) is wrong because we don't say _the same like_.

Comment: So, in a formal context, you would go for "Your team is working on the same research areas as I am.", right?

Comment: Yes, that is grammatically correct (although many people would say 'the same as me' in casual speech).

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you post the comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammatically correct version would be "Your team is working on the same research areas as I am [working on]. However, many people would say "...the same as me" in casual speech.

"The same like me" is not idiomatic English.